# why java logger overwrite the log file?

Tags: java, perl

I have a java application which runs with Perl script.
In Perl, I have configured the log file properties path.
Every time I run the application, it overwrites the log file.
I want to have a new file with a unique name every time that I execute it, and not be overwritten or just a one file but loges be appended at the end of the file.

Any idea why, and how to fix it?

**logconf.properties**

```
handlers= java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level= WARNING

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern= /pipa/log/waach_%u_%g.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.append=true

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

com.xyz.foo.level = SEVERE
ci.pipa.tari.level = INFO
```

**.Perl script**

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use POSIX;

my $java = "/usr/bin/java";

my $classpath  = "/pipata/java/lib/pipatar.jar";
my $properties = "-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/pipata/java/log/logconfig.properties";
my $mainClass  = "ci.pipa.upload.RunPipaFile";

my $command = " $java -cp $classpath $properties $mainClass 2021 2";

print "$command \n";

system ("$command");
```

Comment: Note that `-w` and `use warnings` do pretty much the same thing, so you only need one of them. Most people go with `use warnings`.

Comment: Where did you get your current configuration file from?

Comment: From properties `logconfig.properties` file as you see in the `.perl` file.

Comment: Consider applying, in the perl script, a regex replacement over the configuration file to modify the pattern attribute to force what you desire. From the documentation, a standard configuration file solution does not seem to exist.

Comment: I don't get it what you suggested, could you please give me a simple example.

Comment: Does this happen when you remove Perl from steps and simply run the command on its own?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to API, `java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit`
specifies an approximate maximum amount to write (in bytes)
to any one file. If this is zero, then there is no limit.
(Defaults to no limit).

In my case, 5000 was not enough and every time I run, it adds the rest of the content to a new file which was overwritten the original file. I set the limit to zero, now it appends the log at the end of content inside the same file.

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 0
```